# Garbage Collector asp.net

Tags: asp.net, garbage-collection

Can any one please explain me.

What is the algorithm of garbage collector?

How garbage collector works in background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> GCs only occur when the heap is full.
>   When the garbage collector starts
>   running, it makes the assumption that
>   all objects in the heap are garbage.
>   In other words, it assumes that none
>   of the application's roots refer to
>   any objects in the heap. Now, the
>   garbage collector starts walking the
>   roots and building a graph of all
>   objects reachable from the roots. For
>   example, the garbage collector may
>   locate a global variable that points
>   to an object in the heap.
>
> Following Figure shows a heap with
>   several allocated objects where the
>   application roots 1 refer directly to
>   objects Obj1, Obj2 and application
>   root 2 refer to Obj4 and obj5. All of
>   these objects become part of the
>   graph. When adding object Obj2 of
>   application root 1, the collector
>   notices that this object refers to
>   object Obj7 is also added to the
>   graph. The collector continues to walk
>   through all reachable objects
>   recursively.

[image]
*...Continued [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ankithakur/GCAlgorithm12222005224854PM/GCAlgorithm.aspx?ArticleID=e19fe212-d7e4-469f-bead-c6b32660c389)*

Here are a couple of other links to get you reading on Garbage collection:

- [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/garbagecollection.aspx)
- [AspAlliance](http://aspalliance.com/828)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the basic idea for the GC.

==========================================

Every application has a set of roots. Roots identify storage locations, which refer to objects on the managed heap or to objects that are set to null.

For example:

-- All the global and static object pointers in an application. 
-- Any local variable/parameter object pointers on a thread's stack. 
-- Any CPU registers containing pointers to objects in the managed heap.
-- Pointers to the objects from Freachable queue

The list of active roots is maintained by the just-in-time (JIT) compiler and common language runtime, and is made accessible to the garbage collector's algorithm